# Choice of platform for running web site on Amazon EC2 Linux instance using Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mono, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm a Microsoft guy feeling pretty confident building ASP.Net sites running on Windows. That's basically what I do for a living.

Now I'm considering building a Facebook web app on my own and started looking for hosting solutions. I found the [Amazon Web Services Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) offer pretty compelling. And having the web site in the cloud also seems like a good idea if it becomes popular.

The problem with the offer is that it's only for Linux instances and I don't know squat about that platform.

I've planned to use Solr as my search engine (and perhaps the only data store) since I'm familiar with it and it's just great from a performance and feature standpoint.

Right now I can see two alternatives that both have pros and cons.

**Ruby on Rails**
I don't know the platform or language but it seems to have pretty good integration with Solr. It would be fun to try something completely different and RoR seems very popular right now.

**Mono**
I would be familiar with the platform and the language but it seems to lack in Solr integration.

Any thoughts or pointers to resources would be great. Like I said, I feel a bit lost stepping outside of my comfort zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to advise someone with completely different background. First you have to forget for a minute all that you know about Linux :)
I would try heroku.com
You don't need to know Linux to deploy to heroku. They have a free plan and they have a Solr add-on, $20/month though.
Be warned: If you go RoR route you may never come back to ASP.NET again. No kidding.

Comment: I just created an account :) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: That really hits me deep. Looking forward for Rails and Heroku questions :)